# How to add different graphs (as an inset) in another python graph

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I'd like to make a graph like that:

[image: Ilustrative Figure from google]

the problem is, I've got the data from some external files, and I can make the background graph, but I have no idea how to add another graph inside of the one that I already have and change the data to have different results in both of them:

Below I am adding the code I am using to do the background graph.
Hope someone can help.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('text',usetex=True)
font = {'family':'serif','size':16}
plt.rc('font',**font)
plt.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':14})

matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r'\usepackage{amsmath}']

data=np.loadtxt(r'C:\...\file.txt')
plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,6],linewidth = 3,label='B$_0$ = 1.5 T d',linestyle= '--', color='black')

plt.show()
```

Comment: For more options see answers [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458580/embedding-small-plots-inside-subplots-in-matplotlib).

Comment: For information specific to zoom insets, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277080/add-linear-plot-to-existing-symlog-plot) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583153/how-to-zoomed-a-portion-of-image-and-insert-in-the-same-plot-in-matplotlib).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There's more than one way do to this, depending on the relationship that you want the inset to have.

If you just want to inset a graph that has no set relationship with the bigger graph, just do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# These are in unitless percentages of the figure size. (0,0 is bottom left)
left, bottom, width, height = [0.25, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2]
ax2 = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])

ax1.plot(range(10), color='red')
ax2.plot(range(6)[::-1], color='green')

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to have some sort of relationship between the two, have a look at some of the examples here: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#insetlocator

This is useful if you want the inset to be a "zoomed in" version, (say, at exactly twice the scale of the original) that will automatically update as you pan/zoom interactively.

For simple insets, though, just create a new axes as I showed in the example above.

Comment: `fig.add_axes()` wasn't working for me in Jupyter. `fig.axes()` did the trick.

Comment: Is there a way to add axes to each subplot in a figure but with coordinates relative to the subplot?

Comment: Never mind, just had to scroll down to discover `inset_axes`.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with `inset_axes` method (see [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes.html)):

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
inset_ax = inset_axes(parent_axes,
                    width="30%", # width = 30% of parent_bbox
                    height=1., # height : 1 inch
                    loc=3)
```

See [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html) for a full demo.