# Inset graph, when using a legend placed outside the parent graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to inset a graph inside the parent graph following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001088/how-to-add-different-graphs-as-an-inset-in-another-python-graph).

However, the plotting framework I am using is quite different:

1) First of all, the Legend is located outside the graph, for which I have followed the second answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot), i.e. via shrinking the parent graph:

```
plt.figure()
# Shrink current axis by 20%
box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
```

2) For the labeling, I am using the `ax1.legend((p1, p2, p3), ("label for p1", "label for p2", "label for p3"))` procedure.

If I ran the code with `plt.show()` and `sys.exit()` commented, the entire graph is produced:

[image]

However when implementing the inset answer, and trying to inset to the area of the pink and blue data:

(1) Replace `plt.figure()` by `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()`,

(2) Using a `ax2` for the inset, since a `ax1` has already been used for placing the legend outside the graph,

(3) Uncomment`plt.show()` and `sys.exit()`,

no data is plotted both in the parent and inset graphs:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import sys

x_1 =  np.array([ 2.56480648,  2.56635664, 2.57565757, 2.59425943, 2.61906191, 2.64463946,
  2.66711671, 2.69966997, 2.72292229, 2.75392539, 2.79422942, 2.81360636,
  2.84460946, 2.88026303, 2.91746675, 2.94846985, 2.99187419, 3.01822682,
  3.06085609, 3.08565857, 3.12286229, 3.18331833, 3.24067407, 3.25772577,
  3.36158616, 3.35616062, 3.43056806, 3.45847085, 3.61574815, 3.65387259,
  3.89764927, 9.1       ])


x_2 =  np.array([ 5.77982798, 5.77827783, 5.79067907, 5.81083108, 5.82788279, 5.85113511,
  5.87438744, 5.89763976, 5.92011701, 5.94414441, 5.96584658, 5.98987399,
  6.01467647, 6.03637864, 6.06118112, 6.08443344, 6.11543654, 6.13248825,
  6.16194119, 6.18751875, 6.21077108, 6.23479848, 6.26192619, 6.29137914,
  6.32083208, 6.35028503, 6.38128813, 6.41306631, 6.45569557, 6.47894789,
  6.50530053, 6.55645565, 6.5959846 , 6.62853785, 6.67349235, 6.71612161,
  6.76417642, 6.80293029, 6.86726173, 6.91841684, 6.96182118, 7.04165417,
  7.10908591, 7.23774877, 7.30208021, 9.40021502])


y_1 =  np.array([   0.,     10.,    30.1,  50.2,   70.3,   90.4,   110.51,  130.61,  150.71,
  170.81, 190.91, 211.01, 231.11, 251.21, 271.31, 291.41, 311.52, 331.62,
  351.72, 371.82, 391.92, 412.02, 432.12, 452.22, 472.32, 492.42, 512.53,
  532.63, 552.73, 572.83, 592.93, 592.93])


y_2 =  np.array([   0.,     10.,     30.1,    50.2,    70.3,    90.4,   110.51,  130.61,  150.71,
  170.81, 190.91, 211.01, 231.11, 251.21, 271.31, 291.41, 311.52, 331.62,
  351.72, 371.82, 391.92, 412.02, 432.12, 452.22, 472.32, 492.42, 512.53,
  532.63, 552.73, 572.83, 592.93, 613.03, 633.13, 653.23, 673.33, 693.43,
  713.54, 733.64, 753.74, 773.84, 793.94, 814.04, 834.14, 854.24, 874.34,
  894.44])

x_3 =  np.array([ 273.15, 323.15, 373.15, 423.15, 473.15])
x_4 =  np.array([ 295.16725084, 378.53216084, 476.23703528, 490.56204235])
y_3 =  np.array([ 1.4709975, 1.42196425, 1.372931  , 1.32389775, 1.2748645 ])
y_4 =  np.array([ 1.43766266, 1.46267139, 1.51159861, 1.52367087])


### Plotting:
plt.figure()
#fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

p1  = plt.scatter(x_1, y_1, color='red', marker='o',  s=40)
p3 = plt.scatter(x_2, y_2, marker="o", color='black', facecolors='none', s=40)
p3c = plt.scatter(y_3, x_3, color='magenta', marker="o", facecolors='none', s=40)
p4  = plt.scatter(y_4, x_4, color='blue', marker='o',  s=40)

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('12')

ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
# Shrink current axis by 20% in order to allow the legend to be outside the plot:
box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

ax1.legend((\
p1,\
p3,\
p3c,\
p4\
),\
(\
"1",\
"2",\
"3",\
"4"\
),\
prop=fontP, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))#  loc=4)
extraticks=[273.15+25]
plt.yticks(list(plt.yticks()[0]) + extraticks)
plt.gca().set_xlim(right=8)
plt.gca().set_ylim(bottom=-41.72, top=1040)
plt.grid()

plt.show()
sys.exit()

left, bottom, width, height = [0.25, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2]
ax2 = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])

p3 = ax2.scatter(x_2, y_2, color='black', marker="o", facecolors='none', s=40)
p3c = ax2.scatter(x_3, y_3, color='magenta', marker="o", facecolors='none', s=40)

ax2.set_xlim(right=2.26)
plt.gca().set_ylim(bottom=200, top=1040)
plt.grid()

plt.savefig('plot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')


plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, is this depending on the actual data you have? Can you rather produce a [mcve] with just enought data hardcoded or generated within the code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for your comment and sorry for the inconvenience. I have hardcoded the just enough data in the code, please see updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are simply some useless commands all over the place which make the code produce 2 figures instead of one and several subplots instead of one. Also the limits of the inset seem to be off. Removing all of this would give you the following plot, which might be what you're after.

```
### Plotting:
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

p1  = plt.scatter(x_1, y_1, color='red', marker='o',  s=40)
p3 = plt.scatter(x_2, y_2, marker="o", color='black', facecolors='none', s=40)
p3c = plt.scatter(y_3, x_3, color='magenta', marker="o", facecolors='none', s=40)
p4  = plt.scatter(y_4, x_4, color='blue', marker='o',  s=40)

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('12')

box = ax1.get_position()
ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

ax1.legend((p1,p3,p3c,p4),("1","2","3","4"),
           prop=fontP, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

extraticks=[273.15+25]
plt.yticks(list(plt.yticks()[0]) + extraticks)
plt.gca().set_xlim(right=8)
plt.gca().set_ylim(bottom=-41.72, top=1040)
plt.grid()

left, bottom, width, height = [0.25, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2]
ax2 = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])

p3 = ax2.scatter(x_2, y_2, color='black', marker="o", facecolors='none', s=40)
p3c = ax2.scatter(x_3, y_3, color='magenta', marker="o", facecolors='none', s=40)

plt.grid()

plt.savefig('plot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There were also wrong assignments on `x_i` and `y_i`