# Add linear plot to existing symlog plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some 2d data which I plot using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def f():
    x=np.linspace(0,100,20000)
    return x, np.sin(x)*np.exp(x)

#this is the plotting function 
def symp(l,label,x_scale,y_scale):
    linthresh=10e-32
    for i in range(len(l)):
        style=[':','dashed','dashdot','dotted']
        dashes=[(5, 1),(3, 5),(3, 5, 1, 5), (1,1)]
        col=['Red','Green','Orange','Blue']
        csfont = {'fontname':'Leelawadee UI'}
        line= plt.plot(l[i][0],l[i][1])
        plt.xscale(x_scale)
        plt.yscale(y_scale,linthreshy=linthresh)
        plt.xticks(fontsize=10, fontweight='bold',**csfont)
        plt.yticks(fontsize=10, fontweight='bold',**csfont)
        plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=26, fontweight='bold',**csfont)
        plt.ylabel(label,fontsize=26, fontweight='bold',**csfont)
        plt.setp(line, linestyle=style[i],color=col[i],dashes=dashes[i])
        plt.locator_params(axis='y')
    plt.tight_layout()
    # plt.savefig(str(label+'.eps'), format='eps')
    plt.show()


symp([f()],r'${v}_{a}(x)$','log','symlog')
```

[image]
My goal is to plot only part of 1 array (for example f()[200:1000]) but linearly on the main plot. (In other words, I'm just zooming on my plot, I need it for my paper):
[image]
How can I do this properly?

Comment: We don't need to see your loading code. We need an MCVE. Generate some suitable random data and show exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the plots.

Comment: That helps, but it's still not an mcve. Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21001088/2988730?

Comment: Searching online for something like this is more likely to yield a result than asking an incomplete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [How to add different graphs (as an inset) in another python graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001088/how-to-add-different-graphs-as-an-inset-in-another-python-graph) ,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def zsymp(l,label,x_scale,y_scale):
    linthresh=10e-32
    zf=np.where(va[0][1] > 0, va[0][1], np.inf).argmin()
    f=200
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    for i in range(len(l)):
        style=[':','dashed','dashdot','dotted']
        dashes=[(5, 1),(3, 5),(3, 5, 1, 5), (1,1)]
        col=['Red','Green','Orange','Blue']
        csfont = {'fontname':'Leelawadee UI'}
        line= plt.plot(l[i][0],l[i][1])
        plt.xscale(x_scale)
        plt.yscale(y_scale,linthreshy=linthresh)
        plt.xticks(fontsize=10, fontweight='bold',**csfont)
        plt.yticks(fontsize=10, fontweight='bold',**csfont)
        plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=26, fontweight='bold',**csfont)
        plt.ylabel(label,fontsize=26, fontweight='bold',**csfont)
        plt.setp(line, linestyle=style[i],color=col[i],dashes=dashes[i])
        plt.locator_params(axis='y')
    left, bottom, width, height = [0.2, 0.3, 0.28, 0.28]
    ax2 = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])
    line2=ax2.plot(l[0][0][zf-f:zf+f],l[0][1][zf-f:zf+f])
    plt.setp(line2, linestyle=style[0],color=col[0],dashes=dashes[0])
    # plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def f():
    x=np.linspace(0,100,20000)
    return x, np.sin(x)*np.exp(x)
zsymp([f()],r'${v}_{a}(x)$','log','symlog')
```

I achieved my desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [`outset` library](https://github.com/mmore500/outset) can streamline orchestration of inset plots in matplotlib and add nice zoom indicator annotations to show how the main and inset plots relate.

[image: example outset plot]

## Code

```py
# adapting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65280421/17332200
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt   # ========= Setup =========
import numpy as np
import outset as otst
xdata = np.linspace(0, 100, 20000); ydata = np.sin(xdata) * np.exp(xdata)

grid = otst.OutsetGrid( # ======= Manager for Main/Inset Axes ========
    [[(1, 2), (3, 8)]],  # zoom area coords (x0, y0), (x1, y1)
    marqueeplot_source_kws={  # zoom indicator styling, main axes
        "leader_stretch": 0, "frame_edge_kws": dict(ls=":", lw=5),
        "mark_glyph_kws": dict(markersize=30)},
    marqueeplot_outset_kws={  # zoom indicator styling, inset axes
        "leader_stretch": 0.2, "leader_stretch_unit": "inches"},
    aspect=2, height=4, zorder=4
)

otst.inset_outsets(  # ========= Arrange layout of inset axes =========
    grid, insets=[(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4)],  # position inset axes
    equalize_aspect=False, strip_ticks=False  # mismatching aspects ok
)

grid.broadcast(  # =========  plot same content on both axes =========
    plt.plot, xdata, ydata, linestyle=":", color="Red", dashes=(5, 1)
)

grid.source_axes.set_xscale("log")  # ========= finalize main axes ====
grid.source_axes.set_yscale("symlog", linthresh=10e-32)
grid.source_axes.set_xlabel("x", fontsize=26, fontweight="bold")
grid.source_axes.set_ylabel("${v}_{a}(x)$", fontsize=26, weight="bold")

grid.marqueeplot(equalize_aspect=False)  # ========= Zoom Indicators ===
plt.show()  # Fin!
```

To install the library, `python3 -m pip install outset`.

## Additional Features

Inset axes can also plotted on independently --- instead of using `broadcast` to plot content, access the main axes as `grid.source_axes` and the *n*th accessory axes as `grid.outset_axes[n]`.

In addition to explicit specification as above, the library also provides a seaborn-like data-oriented API to infer zoom inserts containing categorical subsets of a dataframe.

Refer to the outset [*quickstart guide*](https://mmore500.com/outset/quickstart.html) and [*gallery*](https://mmore500.com/outset/gallery.html) for more info.

***Disclosure**: am library author*