matplotlib zoomed in x-axis at beginning and end
i have a signal with a relativly high frequency and i want to have a detailed look at the start of the recorded signal and the end. Like the signal is 1 hour long and i want the first 10 seconds and the last 10 seconds kind of zoomed in (on the x-axis) and the middle section "normal". I allready found this method 'axs.set_yscale('function', functions=(forward, inverse))' which should be able to define a custom scale, but i'm unable to understand how this works and i can not find a lot of documentation on this method.
I can not share the real data, but the data looks very similar to a sinus, so one can use this plot to visualize it:
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0, 1000 * np.pi, 0.1)
y = 2 * np.sin(x) + 3
axs.plot(x, y)


To help you better, could you clarify a few things about your setup?
Could you share a sample of your data or a snippet of your code that shows how you're currently plotting the signal?
Are you open to using separate subplots for the 'zoomed-in' views of the start and end sections, with a normal view for the middle?
If you prefer a single plot with a custom x-axis transformation, could you let me know if you've tried any specific transformations with set_xscale or set_yscale? Sometimes splitting the plot into sections is more effective for this kind of detail.

i edited the question with more information on the signal. I allready looked into the method with plitting the plot into sections, but it looks to me more as a hack or workarround then a real solution. I was thinking there might be a cleaner way by using a custom scale. But if this is not possible that way or even more hacky i will use the split option.

The less confusing solution is to show several figures. You can consider using a log scale sometimes too.

Also a good tradeoff could be the use of insets as in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001088/how-to-add-different-graphs-as-an-inset-in-another-python-graph or https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#insetlocator . It is fine because from your snippet it is a periodical signal, look at figures 10.2 and 10.3 here : https://edoc.unibas.ch/96619/1/Moritz%20Weegen%20online_version%20Phd%20thesis.pdf

The proper link for inset axes is https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html

I think this is basically what you want.  This maps 0-10 to 0-10, 10 to 30 pi to 10 to 20, and 30pi-10 to 1000 pi from 20 to 30 (eg 1/3 each).  It includes extra values one either side in case your data extends beyond the limits you have specified.
(Edit I only went to 30 pi because the plot was just a blue splotch if you went to 1000 pi, but its the same idea)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0, 30 * np.pi, 0.1)
y = 2 * np.sin(x) + 3
axs.plot(x, y)

xdata = np.array([-1e6, 0, 10, np.max(x) - 10, np.max(x), 1e6])
# make 0 to 10 linear, 10 to max(x)-10 much faster linear
# max(x)-10 to max(x) slower linear
xnew = np.array([-1e6, 0, 10, 20, 30, 1e6])


def forward(x):
    return np.interp(x, xdata, xnew)


def inverse(x):
    return np.interp(x, xnew, xdata)

axs.set_xscale('function', functions=(forward, inverse))



BTW, I agree with some of the comments, that you may want to just use three subplots, or inset axes.
