# Different x and y scale in zoomed inset, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, insets

I am trying to make an inset plot using matplotlib. Currently I have something like the last answer in 
[How to zoomed a portion of image and insert in the same plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583153/how-to-zoomed-a-portion-of-image-and-insert-in-the-same-plot-in-matplotlib)

There is a parameter there which determines the zoom factor. However, I want to change the scale between the x and y axes, ie I want to zoom in more on the xaxis. (so in the example, the square would be mapped to a rectangle under the inset map).

How do I achieve this?

Here is a working example:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset

x=np.linspace(0,1,100)
y=x**2

ax=pl.subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)

axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 1, loc=2,bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, 0.55),bbox_transform=ax.figure.transFigure) # zoom = 6



axins.plot(x,y)

x1, x2= .4, .6
y1,y2 = x1**2,x2**2
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=1, loc2=3, fc="none", ec="0.5")
pl.show()
```

So what I want to do is to be able to change the width and height of the inset separately, without changing the x and y ranges of the inset.

Comment: Can you provide some working example code of what you have so far?

Comment: Anyone make any progress on this? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For anyone else looking for this, it turns out this can be accomplished by using the `inset_axes()` method rather than `zoomed_inset_axes()`.

For example:

```
axins = inset_axes(ax, 1,1 , loc=2,bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, 0.55),bbox_transform=ax.figure.transFigure) # no zoom
```

The `1,1` section sets the width and height of the inset, respectively. After this, use the `xlim()` and `ylim()` to set the extents of the axes without changing the size or shape of the inset box.

Comment: Worked like a sharm. I used `axins = inset_axes(ax, 3, 1, loc=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, 0.55), bbox_transform=ax.figure.transFigure) # no zoom` in order to zoom only the x-axis.