# ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.externals'

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, seaborn

When I run file1.py using seaborn.heatmap in python3 on Ubuntu 16.04,

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file1.py", line 19, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
ImportError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

Then I run the command `$ sudo apt install python3-seaborn` in terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdsdp-5.8gf libglade2-0 libglpk36 python-cvxopt python-cycler
  python-decorator python-glade2 python-imaging python-jdcal python-joblib
  python-numexpr python-openpyxl python-pandas python-pandas-lib python-patsy
  python-py python-pytest python-scipy python-statsmodels
  python-statsmodels-lib python-tables python-tables-lib
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-matplotlib
Suggested packages:
  ffmpeg ipython3 python-matplotlib-doc python3-cairocffi python3-gobject
  python3-nose python3-pyqt4 python3-sip python3-tornado ttf-staypuft
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-matplotlib python3-seaborn
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,999 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package python3-matplotlib.
(Reading database ... 378283 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-matplotlib_1.5.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-matplotlib (1.5.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-seaborn.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-seaborn_0.6.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-seaborn (0.6.0-1) ...
Setting up python3-matplotlib (1.5.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-seaborn (0.6.0-1) ...
```

Now file1.py can be run successfully, while I run file2.py using Axes3D in python3,
I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file2.py", line 29, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from matplotlib.externals import six
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.externals'
```

Only I run `$ sudo apt remove python3-matplotlib` can file2.py be run:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-lyx libjs-jquery-ui python-matplotlib-data python-tables-data python3-cycler
  python3-dateutil python3-decorator python3-numexpr python3-pandas python3-pandas-lib python3-patsy
  python3-scipy python3-tables python3-tables-lib python3-tz
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python3-matplotlib python3-seaborn
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 13.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 375396 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python3-seaborn (0.6.0-1) ...
Removing python3-matplotlib (1.5.1-1ubuntu1) ...
```

However, python3-seaborn is also removed at the same time. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-seaborn python3-matplotlib`

Comment: Thanks but the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 6):

`sudo apt-get remove python3-matplotlib`

UPD:
and then install it using conventional `pip`-way style:
`sudo pip3 install matplotlib`

Also, @Andy has noticed that the script removes not only `matplotlib` but also `seaborn`. So, you probably will need to install it using `pip` as well.

---

I tried to do what @Bodhi94 suggested but it was not successful. Then I tried to remove `python3-matplotlib` from Ubuntu and it worked out.

Are there any conflicts may arise? Please, let me if any.

Comment: ``The following packages will be REMOVED: python3-matplotlib python3-seaborn``. So you can no longer have seaborn either.

Comment: Am I right that you may install `seaborn` by `sudo pip3 install seaborn` afterwards as well as `matplotlib`?

Comment: Yes, and I suggest you to use ``$ sudo pip3 install --user`` to install it in /usr/lib/ instead of /usr/local/lib/.

Comment: Okay, in this case you do not need `sudo` permissions. It would be okay to run `pip3 install --user packagename`

Answer (score 5):

Try to reinstall matplotlib using following command.

```
 sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid reply, I get error `Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-2IETOR/subprocess32/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-poC2XV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2IETOR/subprocess32/`, same with  sudo's -H flag.

Comment: You need to install setuptools
```sudo pip install -U setuptools```

Comment: I get `Installing collected packages: numpy, six, cycler, python-dateutil, functools32, pytz, pyparsing, subprocess32, matplotlib`
  `Running setup.py install for functools32 ... done`
  `Running setup.py install for subprocess32 ... error` after collection and downloading.

Comment: Running setup.py install for subprocess32 ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-JSMmcZ/subprocess32/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-OFjPbd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Comment: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying subprocess32.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_posixsubprocess' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

Comment: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _posixsubprocess.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_posixsubprocess.o
    _posixsubprocess.c:3:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: You should install gcc ```sudo apt-get install gcc```

Comment: After running `sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade --ignore-installed six` followed by `sudo aptitude install python-dev` (not to keep the listing packages at their current version but to downgrade the listing packages), `sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade --ignore-installed six` can finally be run. But `ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.externals'` still occurs with `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`.

Comment: `$ sudo apt install python3-seaborn` would install matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/, which might have conflict with the original matplotlib in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/. I run `$ sudo pip3 uninstall matplotlib` and `$ pip3 install --user seaborn` (pip install flag "--user" ensures seaborn to be installed in the same directory where currently matplotlib is), then problems are solved.

Comment: I get the following error after executing command:ImportError: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version.

Comment: @zodiac I think the best practice is isolating python environments using virtualenv or anaconda to eliminate those kinds of dependency issues

Answer (score 3):

I replaced in all the Python Files concerned as follow : 
As soon as I got the message 
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.externals'

I did:
-sudo nano /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/**init**.py 
- and I remplace : "from matplotlib.externals import six" by "import six"

Untill there is error left.

Worked perfect since then

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Perhaps would be a good idea to submit a bug report?