# No module named externals in mplot3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to visualize the 3d plot using mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D with matplotlib

I am using python 3 with matplot version '2.1.0' and scikit-learn verison 0.19.0. When i run the code it is producing the following error,

```
from matplotlib.externals import six
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.externals'
```

I tried to solve this issue by removing existing matplotlib and installing again, without any luck.

i am trying to run this code

```
import numpy as np
import mglearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, axes3d


X, y = make_blobs(centers=4, random_state=8)
y = y % 2

X_new = np.hstack([X, X[:, 1:] ** 2])

figure = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(figure, elev=-152, azim=-26)
# plot first all the points with y == 0, then all with y == 1
mask = y == 0
ax.scatter(X_new[mask, 0], X_new[mask, 1], X_new[mask, 2], c='b', cmap=mglearn.cm2, s=60)
ax.scatter(X_new[mask, 0], X_new[mask, 1], X_new[mask, 2], c='r', marker='^', cmap=mglearn.cm2, s=60)
ax.set_xlabel("feature0")
ax.set_ylabel("feature1")
ax.set_zlabel("feature1 ** 2")

plt.show()

Error log after installing sabron package
The minimum supported version is 2.4.6

  ver=ver, min_ver=_MIN_NUMEXPR_VERSION), UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asif/ml-codes/matpolitlib-tutorials/example-two.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, axes3d
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from matplotlib.externals import six
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.externals'
```

Comment: have you seen this https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5633/

Comment: yes, he is using Anaconda but i am not using anaconda

Comment: have you tried this one?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103248/importerror-no-module-named-matplotlib-externals

Comment: i am not using seaborn library , now install it but problem not solved

Comment: Can you provide the full error log?

Comment: The minimum supported version is 2.4.6

  ver=ver, min_ver=_MIN_NUMEXPR_VERSION), UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asif/ml-codes/matpolitlib-tutorials/example-two.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, axes3d
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from matplotlib.externals import six
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib.externals'

Comment: walk through your 2 links many time, but problem not solved

Comment: Place it in the original question, please, it is unreadable in the comments.

Comment: Did you remove the system package for matplotlib? `sudo apt-get remove python3-matplotlib` ?

Comment: i remove it using pip install it following command  sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade --ignore-installed six

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-matplotlib
```

This will remove the version that is located in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` according to your error log.

Comment: thanks it work, @Pierre de Buy!, but now reached following warning /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/__init__.py:18: UserWarning: The installed version of numexpr 2.4.3 is not supported in pandas and will be not be used
The minimum supported version is 2.4.6

  ver=ver, min_ver=_MIN_NUMEXPR_VERSION), UserWarning)

Comment: why pandas package conflict with numexpr 2.4.3 ??

Comment: I don't know the reason of the conflict, but the recipe is similar. Try to uninstall pandas with `sudo apt-get remove python3-pandas` and install via pip instead. It should download the up-to-date numexpr as well.