# Add an instert of a zoomed in section of a map matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've prodeced a map with the following code:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (12, 12))
eng.plot(ax=ax, facecolor = 'dimgray', linewidth = 0.5, edgecolor = 'dimgray')
blbog.plot(ax=ax, color= 'k', alpha = 0.5)
blbog_unpro.plot(ax=ax, column = 'mean_flow', scheme = 'fisher_jenks', k=5, legend = True, cmap = 'plasma', alpha = 0.75)

axins = ax.inset_axis
plt.show()
```

Which produces this map:
[image]

I'd like to add an insert that zooms in on part of the map. I've seen the documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583153/how-to-zoomed-a-portion-of-image-and-insert-in-the-same-plot-in-matplotlib) and therefor have addedd in the following lines to try and do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=[12, 12])

eng.plot(ax=ax, facecolor = 'dimgray', linewidth = 0.5, edgecolor = 'dimgray')
blbog.plot(ax=ax, color= 'k', alpha = 0.5)
blbog_unpro.plot(ax=ax, column = 'mean_flow', scheme = 'fisher_jenks', k=5, legend = False, cmap = 'plasma', alpha = 0.75)

axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 6, loc=1) # zoom = 6
axins.plot()

x1, x2, y1, y2 = 358000, 425000, 500000, 550000
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)
axins.set_xticklabels('')
axins.set_yticklabels('')

ax.indicate_inset_zoom(axins)

plt.show()
```

The problem I have is that I don't know what to include in the axins.plot() command. In the examples they just include the data they have plotted again, but including the lines I used to make the above plot returns an error.

Does anyone have any clues?

Comment: Did you try `blbog.plot(ax=axins)` and `blbog_unpro.plot(ax=axins, column = 'mean_flow', scheme = 'fisher_jenks', k=5, legend = False, cmap = 'plasma', alpha = 0.75)`?

Comment: That is exactly what I should have done, I am a complete muppet. Thank you.